# Cloud9 AMQP: Node JS - Channel not being created

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

Followed this tutorial: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

Developing in cloud9 right now and just trying to get the `send.js` and `receive.js` to work. But the channels aren't seeming created when I run the file. I first try to run send.js by executing `node send.js` and then execute `node receive.js` in another terminal. However, it never seems to connect or create the channel as it doesn't work as the tutorial suggests it should and no log statements within the `amqp.connect()` method are displayed.

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong? Is there a suggested way to debug to see what's going?

Please see:

https://github.com/hhprogram/ProjectSite/blob/master/receive.js

and

https://github.com/hhprogram/ProjectSite/blob/master/send.js

Note: I also tried to follow this post (https://medium.com/@HolmesLaurence/integrating-node-and-python-6b8454bfc272) but got the same bug where the channel was never being created when trying to coordinate between node and Python.

---

The ultimate goal is to have amqp set up such that I can take input from a webpage, have that handled by nodeJS and then sent to a queue to be consumed by a Python script. Then the Python script does some calculations and returns its results to another queue.

Answer (score 3):

In the function:

`amqp.connect('amqp://webdev-bootcamp-hhprogram.c9users.io/', function(err, conn)`

You are not specifing an user and password so by default it tries `guest@guest`.

The guest user is usually only allowed to access the RabbitMQ server from localhost. If you are accesing from another machine (as I suppose seeing the URL you are using), make sure to use an user and password that exists in the server or give permissions to the guest user to access from a remote machine.

More info here:

http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#api_reference

Comment: Appreciate the response. So, I've updated both files and trying to get it to work (connecting using an object) but my `amqp.connect()` is returning an `err` `Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake`. Do I need to somehow set up the username and password before feeding it into the connection? Unsure exactly what I'm doing wrong and have been having a hard time troubleshooting / getting the rabbitmq management console to work to help me debug (followed some post's about setting up on cloud9 but to no avail).

Comment: I see in your updated code, in the connection object that you are indicating the port 8080. By default amqp uses the port 5672 if you have not changed it in the RabbitMQ Server. Try with that port.

And yes, you have to create the user and password in the RabbitMQ server before you can use it in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the help again! I've update my code since and moved my development from Cloud9 just to my local machine. I wasn't able to get the rabbitMQ management console to work on cloud9 so made it simpler. The simple `send.js` and `receive.js` example seems to work and now I'm working to get communication between NodeJS and Python and have nodeJS start the python script that will be doing the 'messaging'. Thanks again.

Comment: Just FYI - I haven't 'accepted' your solution as, though your answers did help me, it didn't exactly lead to me successfully getting this all set up on cloud9. Thus, I thought it might be misleading for other users if I marked it as accepted. You can let me know if you think that's unfair or not.

Comment: Yes, no problem, I share your argument. I'm sorry to not solve your problem with Cloud9 but I'm glad you managed to make it work at your machine. See you at some other time!

Comment: @Jesferman really? I think this should be accepted. It resolves the error contained question.